# Retrieve Databricks Job data

Tags: azure, databricks

I have a Databricks workspace through Azure, and I use the Databricks Job API to run some python scripts that create files.

I want to know if I can retrieve these files created after the job is finished running.

- In Azure, I see a storage account that is associated with the databricks workspace, in the containers, there's a 'job' entry. When I try to access this, I get a `DenyAssignmentAuthorizationFailed` error. I am organisation admin, so getting the right permissions shouldn't be a problem, although I wouldn't know why I don't have access already and presume it's a databricks thing.
- I tried googling and looking through Azure's docs, but there's surprisingly little documentation on Databricks Jobs or its data storage.

Below you find our Job code. This is called over the Jobs API.

```py
# Parse job info
info = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson()
info = json.loads(info)
RUN_ID = info.get("tags").get("multitaskParentRunId", "no_run_id")

# Create directory
run_directory = f"/databricks/driver/training_runs/{RUN_ID}"
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(f"file:{run_directory}")

with open(f"{run_directory}/file.txt", "w") as file_:
    file_.write("Hello world :)")
```

Comment: Can you provide additional details like databricks API code which runs python scripts, a sample python script and where you can see these file in storage account?

Comment: Added a code snippet of our job. The jobs is called over the api, so no code here. Could share a postman but don't see the value. I don't see the files in the storage, that's my whole question, where / how can I find these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From the given code, I can see that the path in which you are creating a directory and then writing a file, is not DBFS but general storage with path `file:/databricks/driver/training_runs`.
- To get the contents of the above path, there is no UI supported in Databricks. You can list the contents using either of the following:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("file:/databricks/driver/training_runs/<your_run_id>/")

#OR

#import os
#print(os.listdir("/databricks/driver/training_runs/demo"))
```

[image]

- If you want to view these files in UI, then you can try writing the files to DBFS instead. You first have to enable the DBFS browser. Navigate to path `Admin Console ->Workspace settings -> DBFS File Browser` and enable it. Refresh the workspace.

[image]

- Now instead of using path as `file:/databricks/driver/training_runs` , you can use path as shown below:

```
run_directory = f"/FileStore/training_runs/demo"
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(f"dbfs:{run_directory}")

with open(f"/dbfs{run_directory}/file.txt", "w") as file_:
    file_.write("Hello world :)")
```

[image]

- Now you can navigate to `Data -> browse DBFS -> FileStore` and click on the required folder that you want to browse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suggest creating a storage account separate from DBFS to house newly created files or External files. You can modify the script to write to that particular storage account or copy after its creation. This is just how we use it. Nothing wrong in writing to DBFS.

In any case, please refer to the link to connect to Azure ADLS/BLOB Storage.

https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/azure-storage.html

It lists several ways to authentication, evaluate which you feel is the safest and proceed with that option.

Hope it helps...

Comment: This is what we are trying to set up. But for debugging reasons it's convenient to have direct access to the job storage.